# A part of a flexdashboard is permanently in "Dark Mode" while the entire dashboard is in "Light Mode". How can I change it?

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard, bootswatch

Maybe it's something very easy to solve, but I haven't found the problem yet.

I started to develop a Dashboard in `Rmarkdown`, `Flexdashboard` and `Shiny`. At some point I tried the **dark theme** and it seems that the navigation bar is in **dark mode** always, and everything else is in **"light" mode**, since I see it in purple color, and it seems to me that it should be orange.

I attach a reference image.

[image: Flexdashboard]

I am using the **"United"** theme: https://bootswatch.com/united/

Here is the YAML header:

[image: YAML]

Does anyone know how to fix it? I don't see where the problem is.

I remain attentive, best regards.

Comment: Restarting your R version, or even making a brand new directory sometimes helps reset R if your CSS/united theme gets messed up. You can control those colors with [these suggestions](https://flexdashboard-pkg.netlify.app/articles/theme.html) to help reset the light/dark modes.

Comment: I have already restarted my version of R, updated it, and also used another directory to create the dashboard but the problem persists, even with other themes like "Simplex" and "Lumen". I will check the link you sent, thanks @DanielJachetta